# How to add parameter at the top level of the elasticsearch results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to experiment if this is possible in Elasticsearch wherein I can add parameter at the top level of the result.

This is a typical result from elasticsearch

```
{
    "_index": "testing",
    "_type": "reading",
    "_id": "bwDimoUBulk-8kIUdLcv",
    "_version": 2,
    "_seq_no": 7468,
    "_primary_term": 15,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "device": {
            "id": 1435
        },
        "service": 3,
        "value": 0,
        "timestamp": 1723672453,
        "created": "2024-08-15T07:54:13+10:00",
        "updated": "2023-01-10T18:57:28+10:00"
    }
}
```

I want to add the `timestamp` in this example

```
{
        "_index": "testing",
        "_type": "reading",
        "_id": "bwDimoUBulk-8kIUdLcv",
        "_version": 2,
        "_seq_no": 7468,
        "_primary_term": 15,
        "found": true,
        "_source": {
            "device": {
                "id": 1435
            },
            "service": 3,
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1723672453,
            "created": "2024-08-15T07:54:13+10:00",
            "updated": "2023-01-10T18:57:28+10:00"
        },
        "timestamp": 1723672453, <-- this is what I want to add in the result
    }
```

I add the `timestamp` at the top level of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment, you cannot change the top-level structure of the Elasticsearch response. I'm afraid you need to do that at the client level. The only control you have over the response fields is whether you want to include them or not https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering